# How make visibility toggler for directive?

Tags: javascript, angular

Please help make visibility toggler for directive. In template i have follow directive:
`<h1 *appTest visibility="true" id="myDirective">navigation:</`h1>

This directive pass visibility var to:

```
import { Directive, Input, OnInit, ViewContainerRef, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTest]'
})
export class TestDirective implements OnInit {

    @Input() visibility: boolean;

  constructor(private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, private template: TemplateRef<Object>) { 

  }

    ngOnInit() {    
        console.log(this.visibility);   
      if(this.visibility) {
        this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.template);
      } else {
        this.viewContainer.clear();
      }
    }  

}
```

But console display:

> undefined

And #myDirective is not displayed on browser. I need show and hide #myDirective depending on the value of the attribute "visibility"

Comment: Have you tried to set a default value for the visibility, e.g. visibility:boolean = false?

Comment: i need get visibility param from attribute

Comment: There are direct ways to show/hide your elements by using `ngIf` directive in your template and assigning a dynamic `boolean` variable to it. However, this method will remove that corresponding template altogether from the DOM (not just keep `visibility: hidden` which only hides it on the page, keeping the space for that element in DOM). Do you simply want to toggle the elements visibility or add/remove the element altogether from DOM based on your input variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you deal with structural directives you should understand how they can be expanded.

For example your template:

```
<h1 *appTest visibility="true" id="myDirective">navigation:</h1>
```

can be rewritten as follows:

```
<ng-template [appTest]>
  <h1 visibility="true" id="myDirective">navigation:</h1>
</ng-template>
```

So my question is: How do you want to get `visibility` input from `<ng-template [appTest]>?`

You have to include your inputs into `*appTest` statement:

Let's think how...

If you write

```
*appTest="prop1Value"
```

then you will get

```
[appTest]="prop1Value"
```

and you can have the following `@Input` in your directive

```
@Input() appTest;
```

or

```
@Input('appTest') visibility;
```

I used alias `@Input(bindingPropertyName)` in the code above.

Then if you want to have more inputs then:

```
*appTest="prop1Value; prop2: prop2Value; prop3: prop3Value"
              ||
              \/

[appTest]="prop1Value" [appTestProp2]="prop2Value" [appTestProp3]="prop3Value"
```

your component should have:

```
@Input() appTest;

@Input() appTestProp2;

@Input() appTestProp3;
```

Anyway your directive looks like built-in `*ngIf` and i would use it if we don't need any additional logic.